# Bootstrap collapse in Angular js

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a problem with using bootstrap collapse ui with angularJs. When I click on arrow button, it's collapsing all items(divs) instead of one. Could any body help me please how can I define selected item(div) to be collapsed instead of all? Here's my code.Thanks.

```
  <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-header">
        <div class="panel-header-info">
          <div class="items_list" *ngFor="let item of items">
            <div class="items_arrow_button" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
              <div class="img">
                <img src="./assets/images/img.png" class="img-responsive">
              </div>
              <span> Test data {{data.data}}</span>
              <i class="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-angle-down': isCollapsed, 'fa-angle-up': !isCollapsed}"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="items_list" [collapse]="isCollapsed">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <h2>First item</h2>
                  <span>{{data.item}}</span>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: errrr this looks like `angular` not `angularjs` ?

Answer (score 0):

Its because `isCollapsed` is the only basis that your collapsible have. Add `isCollapsed` as a property in your `item`. and then use `item.isCollapsed` for the collapse toggle.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same variable for each item.

To solve your problem, you can:

- Store the variable `isCollapse` in the `item` variable but you have to update your model to store a context variable
- Create an `array` of N elements and you handle each state in this array
- Use a directive/component Collapse which handles is own state